# Using np.cumsum on a grouped csv file

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, statistics

I want to use `np.cumsum()` on a csv file for a column of data based on 57 distinct id's represented by a separate column.  My file looks like this:

```
station_id     year           Value
210018         1910            1
210018         1911            6
210018         1912            3
210019         1910            2
210019         1911            4
210019         1912            7
```

I want my output to look like this:

```
station_id     year           Value
210018         1910            1
210018         1911            7
210018         1912            10
210019         1910            2
210019         1911            6
210019         1912            13
```

I am currently using this code, with my initial file called `df`:

```
df.groupby(['station_id']).apply(lambda x: np.cumsum(['Value']))
```

which returns:

```
TypeError: cannot perform accumulate with flexible type
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`np.cumsum(['Value'])`, all by itself, raises

```
TypeError: cannot perform accumulate with flexible type
```

([`np.cumsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html) expects a numerical array as its first argument, not a list of strings.)
Instead use:

```
values = df.groupby(['station_id'])['Value'].cumsum()
```

or, you could modify `df['Value']` directly:

```
In [75]: df['Value'] = df.groupby(['station_id'])['Value'].cumsum()

In [76]: df
Out[76]: 
   station_id  year  Value
0      210018  1910      1
1      210018  1911      7
2      210018  1912     10
3      210019  1910      2
4      210019  1911      6
5      210019  1912     13
```